# Will the com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder.get method wait for response?

Tags: java, jersey-client

I am working on jersey-client 1.19. I have these line of codes to submit a request to server and get the response:

```
Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/post");
String input = "{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}";

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);

if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}
```

I have a question that when the `post` method execute, if the connection to server having problem (slow internet connection it will response after 3 min) then the code `if (response.getStatus() != 201)` will keep running or will wait for the response from the `post` execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line is a `blocking (synchronous)` call to server -

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

It means this line wait for server to respond. Program execution will not continue after this line till some success/error response is received from server.

It means code written after this line -

```
if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}
```

It will wait for complete execution of previous line (post method response).

For information, `Jersey` also supports `non-blocking (asynchronous)` call to server. Check [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) for details. Also, I would suggest not to use old version of `jersey`. Current version is 2.5.1 and there are a lots of difference between `jersey 1.x and 2.x`